# ImageViews in a ScrollView causing lag

Tags: android, imageview, scrollview

I have this problem with an application I am creating with android. Is this a known problem with `ImageView`s? Should I use something other than a `ScrollView`? Is there some kind of caching I should do? I looked around and there seems to be a lot of solutions for a `ListView`, but none for my `ScrollView`.

Comment: It can be a problem depending on how you load/display your images.

Answer (score 1):

First create a Bitmap of your Image and make it's memory smaller by using these methods below

- setSize
- [BitmapFactory.Options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html)  sampleSize

  After that, add the Bitmap to the Imageview

  Also see [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, I ended up making thumbnails on my server and sending those. Who know having more than 2 full-size HD images was going to cause lag?